# Is it possible to add/subtract in one cell, and have it subtract/add in another cell that already has a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, iif-function

Is it possible to add/subtract in one cell, and have it subtract/add in another cell that already has a value?
I am thinking it may be a if function but I can not wrap my head around how I would write out the formula.

Comment: They are all totals of inventory, When I subtract/add from the first column I want it to do the opposite to the second column, so say if i add to the first column i want it to subtract from other column

Comment: And I would like to do it to cells, not the whole columns, sorry. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, I already values in both, so if i change the number in the first cell, how do I have it know if i subtracted or added and have it do the opposite in the other cell?

Comment: I also have a total of the cells. Is there a way to make it add and subtract?

Comment: Also, how to keep the value in the cell, I tried your formula and it added 10 to the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 columns B and C that already contain data. 
And if you Add a number to B you want that number to be subtracted from C.

My recommendation is to write a macro that will work as follows:

First the user selects the two columns and then runs the macro

```
For each row
    Cell c = getCell("C" + row);
    double cval = c.Value;        
    c.type = FORMULA;
    c.Formula = "=" + (cval + getCell("B" + row).Value) + "-B"+row;
    c.Recalculate()
```

Example:

Original:

```
      A     B     C
1    Gas    5    10
2    Air    8    12
```

Replace with:

```
     A     B        C
1   Gas    5    =15-B1
2   Air    8    =20-B2
```

so you only change B, and the value of C is automatically calculated.

Comment: So I looked up how to use macros, could you dumb down your instructions? I am only a beginner user with Excel.