# excel function enter number in one cell subtract it from another

Tags: excel

I believe [Is it possible to add/subtract in one cell, and have it subtract/add in another cell that already has a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406545/is-it-possible-to-add-subtract-in-one-cell-and-have-it-subtract-add-in-another) is the closest I've seen so far, but it still doesn't answer my question.

I have an inventory list in Excel that looks something like this:

[image]

The formula I have is supposed to take the value I enter in D3 and subtract it from B3. However, when I do this, I get this circular reference error:

[image]

Is there any way to make this calculation so when I credit one cell it debits from another? For instance, if I enter "1" in D3, how do I get it to subtract that from "2" in B3?

Comment: Programatically, e.g. using VBA.

Comment: @BigBen I can't use a formula? I was hoping I didn't have to use VBA...not that I can't code in VBA. I only wanted a simple formula.

Comment: A formula that refers to itself and allows the user to enter number does not exist.  While you can technically allow the use of circular references once the user puts in a value the formula will be erased.  Also the allowing of circular references is environment wide and must be re allowed every time the environment is opened.

Comment: No, you need VBA, or a new column such as Good - Total, which you can do math against.

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay, that's what I feared. I thought maybe I wasn't entering my search criteria correctly.

Comment: Can anyone supply me with a link to an example of how to do this in VBA? I'm trying to use a `Do...While` loop to detect when columns D, E, F, and G have numbers entered and those numbers are subtracted from columns B or C, but I keep getting locked into infinite loops.